# Assertion Error In python

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing

When trying to run this code

> ```
> for i in range(N):
>     jobs.append(mp.Process(None,G_Sim,(lmbda,mu,c,skip_cost,simulation_time,Policy,warmup_period,False,)))
> for j in jobs:
>     j.start()
>     j.join()
> ```

I get an assertion Error: Name must be a string

Comment: You cannot expect to get an answer (or up-votes): You have to provide more information. Especially the content of the variables you are using . This cannot be guessed...

Comment: Can you post *all* the relevant code? What is `N`, `G_sim`, etc?

Comment: Which line gives this error and what is the full traceback?

Comment: Okay, i think ill delete this question (it wasnt well thought out). G_Sim is a huge game theory simulation, and would be impractical to post here. (Ill try and cook up a smaller more relevant example.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mp.Process()` function call is defined as below:

```
multiprocessing.Process([group[, target[, name[, args[, kwargs]]]]])
```

The third argument should be a name for the process, as a string. You are passing the following tuple:
    (lmbda,mu,c,skip_cost,simulation_time,Policy,warmup_period,False,)

You should name your arguments. Something like:

```
jobs.append(mp.Process(group=None, target=G_Sim, args=(lmbda,mu,c,skip_cost,simulation_time,Policy,warmup_period,False,)))
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Process`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) expects its third parameter to be the process name, not a tuple of arguments.